# Delete tag [bracket] on QString

Tags: regex, qt, qstring

I get a text with tag like this :

```
  This is [tag=\"value\"]my text[/tag].
```

I want transform it like this :

```
 This is my text.
```

I have seen I have to use QString.remove(QRegExp(myRegexExpression)) but I don't succeed. 
I have tried :

> remove(QRegExp("\[[^>]*\]")

result : `This is .`

Comment: Try `str.remove(QRegExp("\\[[^\\]]*]"));`

Comment: That's almost it. It wirks with :  str.remove(QRegExp("\\\[[^\\\]]*\\\]")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negated character class `[^\\]]` that matches any character but a `]`:

```
str.remove(QRegExp("\\[[^\\]]*\\]"));
```

The problem you have is cause by the `[^>]*` construct that matches any character but a `>` zero or more times that gets past the BB tag boundary and goes up to the last `]` because `*` is a greedy quantifier (i.e. matches as many characters as it can). See [your regex in action](https://regex101.com/r/vX4lI6/1).

My regex ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/vX4lI6/2)) brekadown:

- `\[` - a literal `[`
- `[^\\]]*` - zero or more (greedy, matches as many as it can) characters other than `]`
- `\]` -  a literal `]`.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the `?` operator to your `*` quantifier to make it lazy. Like this:

`\[[^>]*?\]`

This will make your expression match the least amount of characters after matching the opening `[` , and will match the first `]` available after it , instead of the last one.

Comment: There are no lazy quantifiers in QRegExp.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry , I didn't know that, in that case it could be replaced by `\[[^>\]]*\]` ?